# Microsoft Teams Events Attendance Report

Tags: .net, events, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I have created microsoft teams events using calendar/events. I want to get report for that events Is there any api available for same.

As I have use users/userid/onlineMeetings/meetingId/attendanceReports but I am getting UnkownError as this api is for online meeting.

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is not any graph API available to get the attendance report of an event which is created by calendar/event API.

If you wish you may vote for this feature on - [Microsoft Teams Community](https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/forum/ad198462-1c1c-ec11-b6e7-0022481f8472)